# Why do I get an Uncaught TypeError with private JS ES5 class call?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

I am attempting to make a class in JavaScript (ES5). However, when I call one method from another, I get the following error message in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: root.abLog is not a function

The offending article in question (stripped down to show only the relevant parts) is as follows:

```
var abClass = function(options) {

    var root = this;

    this.checkAttach = function(text){
        root.abLog('Checking attached');
        /* snip */
    };

    var abLog = function(data) {
        console.log('abClass PATH: "'+vars.path+'"');
        console.log('abClass: '+data);
    };

};
```

Both `root.abLog('Checking attached');` and `this.abLog('Checking attached');` result in similar errors.

What have I done wrong with what I understand is a private method?

Comment: Can you also include how you instinciate your `abClass` as well as how you call your `abLog` method?

Comment: abLog has nothing to do with `this` hence the error. variables defined inside of a block are not part of `this`

Comment: It is not global, it is scoped to that block.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Comment: Disregard previous comment - it looks like we are looking at this from two ways - one way being that the call of the function is wrong (and doesn't match the definition) and the other being that the definition is wrong (and doesn't match the call).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call it without `root` or `this` like -

```
var abClass = function(options){

   var root = this;

   this.checkAttach = function(text){
       abLog('Checking attached');
       /* snip */
   };

   var abLog = function(data) {
       console.log('abClass PATH: "'+vars.path+'"');
       console.log('abClass: '+data);
   };

};
```

`abLog` is a private function of your `abClass` and the scope of `this` (attached to `root` in your case) gets a copy of your public members of the class, i.e. members directly attached via `this.XXX` - In your case, it's only `checkAttach` attached to `this` (hence making it a `public` member)

Check [this JS bin](https://jsbin.com/renafohuji/3/edit?html,js,console) to play around and debug